What is an argument (in philosophy)?
Closely related (sub)question: is there some way to tell a piece of (spoken, or writen, or...) text that is an argument from one that isn't? If 'yes', how?
[Notice the question is not asking "What is a valid argument? Is there a way to tell a valid argument from an invalid one?", as this assumes some notion/definition of 'argument' is already in place]

See Argument and Argumentation with a large Bibliography: "An argument can be defined as a complex symbolic structure where some parts, known as the premises, offer support to another part, the conclusion. Alternatively, an argument can be viewed as a complex speech act consisting of one or more acts of premising (which assert propositions in favor of the conclusion), an act of concluding, and a stated or implicit marker (“hence”, “therefore”) that indicates that the conclusion follows from the premises."

There is a minimal definition, as in Wikipedia or IEP, which says, basically, that an argument is a list of premises followed by the conclusion, all of them truth-apt. However, in practice, one also expects a chain (or interconnected chains) of inference steps that connect the former to the latter, and the steps are expected to be self-explanatory. This is closer to what is called derivation in formal theories. If a text can be parsed into such chain(s) of inferences philosophers call it an argument.

Yes, there's an entire field of study called argumentation theory which is essentially the philosophy of arguments. There are different models, in Uses of Argument (GB), Stephen Toulmin lays out a good model of argumentation now named after him. From the WP article on argumentation theory:

Argumentation theory is the interdisciplinary study of how conclusions can be supported or undermined by premises through logical reasoning. With historical origins in logic, dialectic, and rhetoric, argumentation theory includes the arts and sciences of civil debate, dialogue, conversation, and persuasion. It studies rules of inference, logic, and procedural rules in both artificial and real-world settings.

Generally, arguments in reason are classified as deductive, inductive, or abductive, or some mix thereof, and the broader notion of argumentation which might use such persuasive factors as emotions, testimony, and fallacies is the object of study under rhetoric which views argumentation as a process that is liable to be highly irrational.

Without getting technical, you have a argument when a conclusion is said to follow from a set of premises. For a deductive argument, If it in fact follows, the argument is classified as valid.  Otherwise the argument is invalid.  Inductive arguments are neither valid nor invalid.
To your subquestion- yes, there is a way to tell you have an argument.  The conclusion will be preceded by words like, Therefore, So, Thus, Hence, etc.
If you want to get technical, you have an argument when a corresponding conditional is claimed to be a tautology.
Suppose you have a set of propositions denoted by statements A1, A2, A3,... An, which we will call premises, and a proposition denoted by B, which we will call the conclusion, if someone claims the proposition denoted by the statement
"IF A1 & A2 & A3 &... &An THEN B"
is a tautology, then they are claiming the conclusion follows from the premises.  Thus they formed an argument.

That is not what an argument is in philosophy and in the general sense.

@julio, that's what it is in logic, logic is a branch of philosophy, so that's what it is in philosophy.

Logic is not a branch of philosophy, but even if it were, you should show how the question boils down to a question of logic and in fact of formal logic, as the OP was explicitly asking for something else.  See my comments to Jo Wehler for more details.
